# Swift 3: how to enable local notification and disable push notification in foreground

Tags: swift3, apple-push-notifications, ios10, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I am using both local and push notification in my app and i receive notification for both in background and foreground but i just want to receive only local notification in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You must threat application state in **didReceiveRemoteNotification**
and use UIApplicationState (can be .active in Swift or UIApplicationStateActive in Objective-C for example) see documentation [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationstate)